# subversion commit completed but files are not being updated on web server

Tags: svn, ubuntu, commit

I have commited my changes on svn but when i check back my web server the files are still the same...

Is there any part i missed and need to do in order to apply the changes on the web server **www folder** as well?

**procedure i follow:**

- log in via versions(subversion client)
- location for repository is svn://username@domain.com
- checkout to folder
- update
- make changes on checkout folder
- commit

Comment: Describe in details what you perform and what you get

Comment: @bmargulies i am new to svn so i guess thats where the updates files should go?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved by changing apaches locationroot to checkout folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your Subversion repository and your web server are not the same thing - committing changes to Subversion does not automatically cause those updates to be propagated to the web server (unless there is a Subversion hook or other process watching the repository for changes to occur, and replicating them).

When you commit your changes to Subversion, you are saying "I have made some changes, tested them on my local web server, and am confident they will work in Production". You must then execute whatever Production deployment process is expected for those committed changes to be applied to the Production web server. This may be as simple as logging-on to the Production web server and refreshing the folder structure containing the site from Subversion - essentially updating a 'working copy' on the web server.

Comment: i am that ready to close 10+ hours of understanding svn so please bear with me... i have commited, then checked my WWW on web server and there is a new folder(my repo) and there inside there is the updated web server files... how the hell did this folder got created and especially why does it contain my updated files and how do i make the updated files go straigh to www folder? thanks for understanding!

Comment: Your explanation of your environment is ... unclear - but the implication is that you have the Subversion repository on the webserver itself. I would strongly recommend against this. My answer already explains why your website folder structure is not being updated when you commit your changes to Subversion.

Comment: so if my svn repo is in /svn/repo where should i checkout? inside repo folder?